# Activities and their lifecycle

Tags: java, android, android-activity, lifecycle

Consider this:

- Activity A
- Activity B
- Activity C

Activity A is started when clicking on launcher icon. Activity B is started by activity A - nothing special. But Activity C should be started ONLY by app itself (not on click or something similar ), like broadcast.

THE PROBLEM:

When Activity C is started by app automatically, and when i press HOME button on this activity, and when i click on lanuncher icon (to show up Main Activity - A ), it shows me activity C. If i press BACK button on this activity, then i can go to activity A, with no problem.

How to solve that issue? Killing activity C, on HOME button press, or is some other way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In manifest of your Activity A put `android:launchMode="singleTask" android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"` and in rest of the Activities put `android:clearTaskOnLaunch="false"`, This will solve your problem. Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 2):

Just add `android:noHistory="true"` to `<activity>` element of Activity C in your AndroidManifest.xml.

Setting `true` for [android:noHistory](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#nohist) will make the activity not leaving a historical trace.  It will not remain in the activity stack for the task, so the user will not be able to return to it.